# How to filter an array with a special condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter some data but I am trying to get all the elements with the same `id` that have the number `3`.

The id `10` and `300` has number `3` so I want to get all the elements with id `10` and `300`

Is it possible to do this using filters? My current code is filtering too much elements

```
const data = [{
    id: 10,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 10,
    number: 2
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 1
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 40,
    number: 1
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    number: 2
  }
]

const filteredData = data.filter(elem => elem.number === 3);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Expected Result:

```
{
      id: 10,
      number: 3
    }, {
      id: 10,
      number: 2
    }, {
      id: 300,
      number: 1
    }, {
      id: 300,
      number: 3
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a `Set` which contains all the `id` you want. Then filter the list again based on the `id`.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 10,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 10,
    number: 2
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 1
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 40,
    number: 1
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    number: 2
  }
]

const ids = new Set(data.filter(d => d.number === 3).map(d => d.id));

const filteredData = data.filter(d => ids.has(d.id));

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: Should be fine for performance. My array is like 1000 entries

Comment: Yes, this solution runs in `O(n)` time which should be fine performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

Using `some()` can also do it

```
data.filter(d => data.filter(d => d.number == 3).map(d => d.id).some(i => i == d.id))
```

```js
const data = [{
    id: 10,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 10,
    number: 2
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 1
  }, {
    id: 300,
    number: 3
  }, {
    id: 40,
    number: 1
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    number: 2
  }
]

let result = data.filter(d => data.filter(d => d.number == 3).map(d => d.id).some(i => i == d.id))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Note that this will be `O(n^2)` (vs `O(n)` if you fetch all ids into a `Set` upfront) which might be too slow for big arrays.

Comment: @Dogbert yes,at this time `Set` might be a better choice as another answer posted